# Gitlab runner with docker-windows executor is pulling linux docker images and failing

Tags: docker, gitlab

I've been running a Gitlab CI runner in a linux server for a while configured with docker executor. This has been working for a while now until I have been asked to add a docker-windows executor to the pool in order to compile windows projects under docker.

It seems that the windows-docker executor is now trying to also execute linux based jobs and failing with the following error:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 14.0.1 (c1edb478)
  on XXXXXXXXXXXXX_
Preparing the "docker-windows" executor 00:14
Using Docker executor with image SOME_LINUX_BASED_IMAGE_HERE ...
Authenticating with credentials from job payload (GitLab Registry)
Pulling docker image SOME_LINUX_BASED_IMAGE_HERE  ...
WARNING: Failed to pull image with policy "always": image operating system "linux" cannot be used on this platform (manager.go:205:2s)
ERROR: Preparation failed: failed to pull image "SOME_LINUX_BASED_IMAGE_HERE" with specified policies [always]: image operating system "linux" cannot be used on this platform (manager.go:205:2s)
```

I have searched Gitlab documentation on how to avoid this but have been unable to do so. How can I configure my runners to avoid this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final configuration to avoid the problem is the following:

- Tag all the runners with the corresponding OS tag when registering a runner.
- Because my organization runs by default on linux, linux runners are configured to allow to pick up jobs without tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign tags to runners and then a specific runner will only accept jobs that have a specific tag.

cf. https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/#tags and https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#tags

---

I introduced OS specific tags for all my runners and configured my default runners (majority is linux) to also accept jobs without tags in order to avoid tagging of all jobs that should run on the default runners.

Comment: Thanks! I will tag the base os in my workers as a temporary solution. Note that my workers are currently tagged as "docker" and "docker-windows". If no tag is specified both runners are viable for execution. This, as far as I know, does not happen with Gitlab shared runners so I would love to see if there is a better solution for this.

Comment: I have found it. It seems there is an additional config that enables a machine to pick jobs without a tag. That should solve my problems! Thank you @MrTux!